# Practice and theory contradicts about Lejos Coordinate system

Tags: java, lego-mindstorms, lejos-nxj

I know the Coordinate system of leJOS is a cartesian coordinate system.The positive X-axis is pointing directly in front of the car. The positive Y-axis points to the left of the X-axis. But I code a progarm and move the car, and then I have an issue:

I make the car go straight with `navigator.goTo(20, 0);`. But with `navigator.goTo( 0, 20);`,it goes to the right instead of the left! I get the pose by `navigator.getPoseProvider().getPose()`. The value of X is `0`, but the value of Y is `20` instead of `-20`!

Why?

Answer (score 0):

now I have soved the question.
Wheel wheel1=WheeledChassis.modelWheel(leftMotor, 3.1).offset(-8.5);
becaues of the offset it should be 8.5